SwiftUI: Use different color schemes for Menu in toolbar and toolbar itself
I'm using a custom Navigation Bar background color. Since the black color of the Navigation Title that's used in .light mode would not be suitable I'm using the .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar) modifier.
This works fine except that I'm also using a Menu in the toolbar which now of course also uses the .dark mode but should use the .light mode instead:

Is it possible to achieve this?
I tried to apply .preferredColorScheme(.light) to the Menu but this doesn't work.
This is my code:
NavigationView {
    List {
        Text("Row Title")
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
            Menu {
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Label("Report an Issue", systemImage: "exclamationmark.bubble")
                }
                Divider()
                Button(role: .destructive) {
                } label: {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                }
            } label: {
                Label("Perform action", systemImage: "ellipsis.circle")
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("My Documents")
    .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
    .toolbarBackground(Color.blue)
    .toolbarBackground(.visible)
}


It sounds like what you really want to do is to set white as foreground color for the navigation title. Then light/dark mode for the menu can be allowed to work normally. See Change NavigationStack title font, tint, and background in SwiftUI for ways of doing this.

Instead of .preferredColorScheme(.light) you can also try .colorScheme(.light). This works differently and only changes the view you applied the modifier to. It will be deprecated soon, but so far it works fine.

Thanks both! tillus, your suggestion unfortunately doesn't work (color scheme isn't applied) but, Benzy Neez, yours does. Thanks again!
